# object's number property is converted to string in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a model with two properties one of which is a number.

```
export class Ingredient
{
    constructor(public name:string,public amount:number)
    {

    }
}
```

However every time I try to add to the amount I actually get concatenation. The weird thing is that when I try to do parseInt to the value I get the error I cannot pass number to parseInt but typeof returns string for the property.

```
addIngredient(ingredient: Ingredient)
{
    let ingredientInList=this.ingredientInList(ingredient);
    //alert(ingredientInList);
    if(ingredientInList!==false)
    {
       // alert(typeof(this.ingredients[ingredientInList].amount));

      this.ingredients[ingredientInList].amount=this.ingredients[ingredientInList].amount + ingredient.amount;
    }
    else
    {
        //alert(typeof(ingredient.amount));

        this.ingredients.push(ingredient);
    }
    this.ingredientsChanged.emit(this.ingredients.slice());
}
```

So when I run the above code the amount next to an ingredient gets concatenated to the previous amount (assuming it has found a similar ingredient already).

Any ideas?

Comment: dirty but probably it works (this.ingredients[ingredientInList].amount * 1) + (ingredient.amount * 1)

Comment: beware the place you defined `this.ingredients` is that an array of Ingredient[] ?!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that type of both "amount" is `number` not string.

otherwise, you can use this below code to parse the number-

```
this.ingredients[ingredientInList].amount = parseInt(this.ingredients[ingredientInList].amount) + parseInt(ingredient.amount);
```